# Limit of the function series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to find the value

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^3+n^3}{k^32^n+1}$$

Hint I've got:

Compare $$\frac{k^3+n^3}{k^32^n+1}$$ with $$\frac{1+n^3}{2^n}$$ and use Weierstrass theorem.

I do not know how to apply Weierstrass theorem with the limit of k.
Help guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\frac{k^3 + n^3}{k^3 2^n +1} -\frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{n^3 - 2^{-n}}{k^3 2^n +1}$ (and $\sum \limits_{n\geqslant 1} \frac{n^3 - 2^{-n}}{k^3 2^n +1}$ converges because the general term is equivalent to $\frac{n^3}{k^3 2^n}$).

So $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^3 + n^3}{k^3 2^n +1} = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1} {2^n} + \frac{1}{k^3} \cdot \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^3 - 2^{-n}}{2^n + \frac{1}{k^3}}$, and all the sums converge.

So finally the limit seeked is $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1+n^3/k^3}{2^n+1/k^3} \leq \frac{1+n^3}{2^n},\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^3+1}{2^n}<+\infty,$$
hence by the Dominated Convergence Theorem we have:
$$ \lim_{k\to +\infty}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1+n^3/k^3}{2^n+1/k^3} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n}=\color{red}{1}.$$